# Adding additional margin to the top a jquery animate function?

Tags: jquery

currently I have a jquery document.ready function that scrolls down to a div after an amount of time, however it leaves a margin on the I'd like to get rid of.

Function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').delay(2000).animate({

        scrollTop: $('.pull-to').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with this?